# Will indexing make find_one() any faster?

Tags: python, python-2.7, indexing, pymongo

If I have a pymongo query, in a collection with around 4000 documents, like the following:

```
mong  =  pymongo.Connection()['ASD_2']['APS2'] 
py_mong = mong.find_one({'plate':'123456'})
```

Considering there is no `.explain()["cursor"]`  or `.explain()["nscanned"]` allowed on `find_one()`, and therefore no method at hand to find out the nature of the scan, can anyone tell me if it's worth indexing the collection when I am only going to be using `find_one()`?

Comment: maybe you can try it using `timeit` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

How do I know?

First, it would be utterly unacceptable if it didn't. People would have complained about the surprising and unnecessary slowness of `find_one` as compared to `find`, and the dev team would have fixed it (or risk being viewed as dumb).

Second, I checked the code. The implementation is exactly what you'd expect, meaning `find_one` is a mere wrapper around `find`:

```
def find_one(self, spec_or_id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if spec_or_id is not None and not isinstance(spec_or_id, dict):
        spec_or_id = {"_id": spec_or_id}
    for result in self.find(spec_or_id, *args, **kwargs).limit(-1):
        return result
    return None
```

(pymongo version 2.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indexing will avoid a linear search of the requested plate and work in logarithmic time (much faster).

Comment: But how do you know, how can you decide the nature the scan performed  with `find_one()`? I know it makes a blistering difference with `find()`, but are you sure it will work for `find_one()` ?

Comment: No reason not to. If you're not sure, run a test and find out!